# how to display image over breadcrumbs in category

Tags: magento2.3.3

hi currently am looking for a solution to add catg image over breadcrumbs. i have added a static block inside catg and displaying both catg and product is there any solution for this.

i just want this image above the breadcrumbs.
thanks in advance

[image]

**update**
i have tried to override breadcrumbs.phtml file in my custom theme and called a static block and the result is working fine over catg page but this image is also visible on home page which i dont want.
my phtml file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>

<!-- calling block in phtml file -->
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('catg-image')
->toHtml();
?>

<!-- breadcrumbs folows here -->
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

pls refer the image below
[image]

[image]

**update**
i have already solved this issue thank you if anyone needs and ans can post a question and i will help him

working .phtml code

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">




    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this image is your category image? which is uploaded from backend category???

Comment: no its a block i just want to know how to ovreride breadcrumbs so that i can call my block above it in phtml file

Comment: answer posted. check and let me know working or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `breadcrumbs.phtml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

and use the code below:

```
<?php
// call your block here
?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thnkss but i have already found a solution and am updating my phtml code

Comment: between do you know how to display catg image above catg name??can we achieve this in same file

Comment: yes you need to add block end of phtml file

Comment: i want the same catg name that is displaying below breadcrumbs above it

Comment: override catalog_category_view.xml file in your theme and put this line <move element="page.main.title" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>