# Displaying image over breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2.3.3

Hi in past i have raised

[this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299877/how-to-display-image-over-breadcrumbs-in-category/299878?noredirect=1#comment432225_299878) on how to display image over breadcrumbs in catg and though i have found an ans by myself but i have also got an ans from peoples

but now am facing another related to this those catg images are visible any new cms page that i have created.
for refrence am putting an image below
[image]

breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">


<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('catg-image')
->toHtml();
?>

    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
             <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and i dont want this image to be displayed in cms pages
thanks in advance

Comment: You want to display images only in category pages. i m right?

Comment: yes exactly over breadcrumbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with below code :

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">


<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

$moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action     = $request->getActionName();

if($moduleName == "catalog" && $controller == "category" && $action == "view") {
    echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
    ->setBlockId('catg-image')
    ->toHtml();
}

?>

    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($crumbName) ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($crumbInfo['link']) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
             <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: ok sir am trying

Comment: yep this works could you please explain your ans?? why mine was not working

Comment: <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

$moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action     = $request->getActionName();

Comment: explain these??

Comment: If your requested url is catalog/category/view then only call your block. means when any request comes from this url then only call this block

Comment: great thanks a lot ! this works like a charm

Comment: you're welcome!